# javascript dynamically add delete row nested

Tags: javascript

I've run into a problem with adding and deleting blank rows in javascript... it's a nesting issue and unique id issue.

To summarize, I have three form fields.   Field1, Amount1, Amount2.    Field1 can have multiple Amount1 & Amount2.   There can be multiple Field1 as well, which also can have mutiple Amount1, Amount2.  The problem is that my "Add" buttons copies the extra Amount1, Amount2 (when exists).  Just to explain, the "Add row" adds Amount1,Amount2.  The "Delete Row" deletes Amount1,Amount2 when the checkbox is checked.

When I click the "Add" button, I want a new Field1, Amount1, Amount2 but no additional Amount1,Amount2.  And when I click "Add Row" or "Delete Row" in the additional sets of form fields, I want it to add or delete the Amount1,Amount2 in that particular set.

I need to assign a unique identifier to each entire row to get this to work but cannot figure it out.

Here is my code, which will probably make more sense if it's executed.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addRow(tableID) {               
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);               
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;             
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);               
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;               
     for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {                   
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);                   
     newcell.innerHTML = table.row[0].cells                                                [i].innerHTML; //alert                                                       (newcell.childNodes);
switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {                     


    case "text":                             
    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";                            
    break;                     
    case "checkbox":                             
    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;                             
    break;                     
    case "select-one":                             
    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;                            
    break;   

    }             
    }         
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {             
     try {             
       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);             
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;               
         for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {                 
       var row = table.rows[i];                 
       var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];                 
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {                     
        if(rowCount <= 1) {                         
           alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");                        
       break;                     
      }  

     table.deleteRow(i);                     
      rowCount--;                    
       i--;                 
       }                 
       }             
       }catch(e) 
       {                 
       alert(e);             
       }         
       }


       var _counter = 0;
       function Add() {
           _counter++;
           var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
           oClone.id += (_counter + "");
           document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
       }

       </script>
       </head>



       <body>

    <fieldset id="fieldset">

        <div id="placeholder">
        <div id="template">


           <br>


    <table  id= "act_legis">
            <tr>
                <td>Field1:</td>
                <td>Amount1:</td>
        <td>Amount2:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table id= "act">
            <tr>  
                <td>
                    <button type="button" name="Submit" 
                     align = "left" onclick="Add();">Add</button>
                    <input name="Field1" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4"/></td>    
            </tr>
    </table>


    <table id= "legis_amounts">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
                    <input name="Amount1" type="text" size="10"maxlength="18"/>
               </td>
      <td>
                 <input name="Amount2" type="text" size="10" maxlength="18"/>
      </td>
           </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
                    <input type="button" onclick="addRow('legis_amounts');
            return false;"  value = "add row"/>
            <input type="button" value = "delete row" onclick="deleteRow
                    ('legis_amounts');return false;"  />
                  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

        </div> <!-- template -->
        </div> <!-- placeholder -->
        </fieldset>

    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `Here is my code, which will probably make more sense if it's executed.` is it too much to ask you to format your code so that it'll make sense when looked at? I mean you've already realised yourself that it can't be understood!!

Comment: I did attempt to format it.  Spent quite some time attempting to do it too !